# Can not pass request parameter to controller from route in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, request

I have

```
public function checkCookie(Request $request) {

// do something 
}
```

in my controller and I am trying to call it from `routes.php` with

```
Route::get('mypage',function(){
    $a=new App\Http\Controllers\indexController;
    $a->checkCookie();               
});
```

but I can't pass request parameter. What am I missing?

Comment: It's a wrong way of approaching the solution. 
Try `Route::get('/mypage', 'indexController@checkCookie');

Comment: Main goal is getting returning value from method

Comment: After changing your route, do `dd($request->all());` to see all your request data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks for helps!!! finally i could pass param with

```
Route::get('mypage',function(Request $request){
    $a=new App\Http\Controllers\indexController;
    $b=$a->checkCookie($request);
    if(!empty($b)){
        return view('mypage');
    }
});
```

and did these configs in my **.env**

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE='db_name'
DB_USERNAME='root'
DB_PASSWORD=''
DB_PORT=3306
```

Comment: It's totally a matter of preference, but it's generally preferred to leave the *routes.php* as simple as possible, leaving the Controller (and other Models) to the programming logic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what this should look like:

routes.php

```
<?php
Route::get('/mypage', 'IndexController@checkCookie');
```

Controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;

class IndexController extends Controller {

    public function checkCookie()
    {
        $data = Request::only('myvariable');
        dd($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also pass variables from the url like: `Route::get('/mypage/{id}', 'IndexController@checkCookie');` and in your controller change the function to `public function checkCookie($id)` - Now $id will be available.